# setTimeout add conditional to function parameter

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Basically, what I want to achieve is the following. I have this function 'ontimeout' that expects a function as a parameter and calls this function only if, after a given time (3s), a condition is true:

```
EventStreamSource.prototype.ontimeout = function(func){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(this.source.readyState == 0){
            func()}
    }, 3000);   
};
```

In another script, there could be code like:

```
source.ontimeout(function(){
    toastr.error('Command stream not established.')
})
```

However, this does not seem to work. I am not all that familiar with javascript and I am sure I've been making a rooky mistake but I've also been banging my head on this far too long so it would be great to have a couple of extra eyes on this.

So the actual question is how to invoke 'func' in a new function().

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why you think it _does not seem to work_? are you try it? Can you provide jsfiddle for you problem?

Comment: You are invoking the function the right way. Just  `func()`. Maybe the problem is that `source` variable I'm not sure where it comes from.

Comment: yes, this should trigger a notification on the including page but it doesn't.
i did just notice that an alert statement after the if is also not working. the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: source is a variable to the EventStreamSource object. it should be this.source, but this did not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your function passed to `setTimeout` function creates its own `this` context, so `this` no longer refers to the the instance of `EventStreamSource`. Pass `this.source` via a closure like below:

```
EventStreamSource.prototype.ontimeout = function(func){
    (function(source){ // accept source as an argument to the closure
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(source.readyState == 0){
                func()}
        }, 3000);
    })(this.source); // pass this.source to the closure
};
```

Comment: source is a property of the EventStreamSource object, it should thus be this.source.readyState.
I tried using your code but this did not change anything.

Comment: see edit - you need to pass `this.source` to the closure because your setTimeout function creates its own `this` context which is not the EventStramSource.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! I would have never found this solution on my own. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without the IIFE (or closure or whatever you want to call it) but that solves the same issue: the function passed to setTimeout creates its own `this` scope, so first we dereference `this.source` into a variable.

```
EventStreamSource.prototype.ontimeout = function(func){
    var thisSource = this.source;

    setTimeout(function(){
        if(thisSource.readyState == 0){
            func()}
    }, 3000);   
};
```